# Crystal Report Loading issue due to images

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Currently I am working with crystal report which shows images of large size. I am facing difficulty at the time of load. So now I want to element crystal report as I cant reduce quality of images. Any alternate way to do the same thing?? And yes I don't want to use third party control..

Thank you in advance...

Comment: You can use a XSLT for this. You an put the information to be displayed in the report including the image url in to a XML and then transform the XML using your XSLT. The output will be in html.

Comment: @Kosala W: Thank you so much for suggestion. I will look after this but I don't know much about XSLT. So may be it would be difficult for me. If you can give me more details or good tutorial links then it would be more helpful..Thank you!!!

Comment: This is a very basic one. Remember XSLT has all the basic features of a programming language. So more you explore more you discover. The best thing about XSLT is the speed. It can process faster than any other reporting tool. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp

Comment: @KosalaW: Thank you so much for this good suggestion. But right now I have permanently solved this issue by decreasing the quality of images..But I will implement your suggestion in my next project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.. Actually problem was used resources for report viewer. I was disposing my crystal report object but not crystal report viewer object. So

```
 viewer.dispose();
```

worked for me..

I hope same solution helps any one facing the same issue..

Thank you for your great response too!!!